# Any solution for uploading an image to firebase?

Tags: forms, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my app I have a "create product" page where there is a form where the user will fill in product data and at the bottom of the form I have a `ImagePicker` where the user will select an image from their gallery for the product.

Here is how the code looks:

```
Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    final imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    setState(() {
      data.image = imageFile;
    });
    final appDir = await syspaths.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);
    final savedImage = await imageFile.copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
  }
```

here are the packages used:

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as syspaths;
```

but when submitting my data into Firebase with a save button since the image is a file I keep getting this error:

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of '_File'
```

How can I upload the image into Firebase and let it be stored for that product and not mix it randomly? and to follow the ID of the product? and if its possible or not.

Comment: FYI backtick quotes are used to mark bits of code.  They're not used to highlight text.

Answer (score 1):

i use this approach to upload the files and get the URL link

```
 Future uploadFile(File file) async {
    String fileName = basename(file.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStroageReference =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);

        StorageUploadTask   _uploadTask = firebaseStroageReference.putFile(file);

    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await _uploadTask.onComplete;

    var dowurl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    setState(() {
     _url = dowurl.toString();
    });

  }
```

don't forgot the plugin

```
firebase_storage:
```

Comment: Your first setState evaluates a Future, but doesn't await for it before the setState.  This is a protocol problem, as the setState should be executed only when everything referenced is resolved.

Comment: @suhaibsalem i got an error in your code the `_url` is underlined in red this is the error im getting `Undefined name '_url'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.`

Comment: Also does providing this method make the Image appear for all users? or does it just store the file path? like you said itll give a `URL` link in return do I change my content Display from `Image.file()` to `NetworkImage()`??

Comment: 'String _url' outside the method

Comment: of course change it to NetworkImage() because you want to store the images in the Firestore not locally